# C++ sharing object between two class

Tags: c++, c++11, observer-pattern, constructor-injection

Suppose I have two class: `FirstContainer` and `SecondContainer` 
They hold the same reference (pass in their constructor) to the class `ThirdContainer`. 
FirstContainer and SecondContainer have the following methods: 
 - `addMemberToThirdContainer` 
 - `delMemberOfThirdContainer` 
 - `getThirdContainerMembers`

When the ThirdContainer is modified, I want the two others to update using `getThirdContainerMembers()`. For this purpose I use the *observer/listener pattern*.

`ThirdContainer` has a list of listener and a method: `addNewListener`. 
`FirstContainer` and `SecondContainer` register by doing: `mThirdContainer.addNewListener(this);`

I'm not sure this is the good way to do this, I'm new to oriented object.
What are my other possibilities to achieve something like that ?
 
I'm not attached to anything I stated, it's just here because I have hard time to explain what I want to do. I hope it's clear. 
Thanks for the help, 
 
Best,

Edit:
What a bout using forward declaration ? I could do something like:

```
 class ParentContainer {
 public:
     ParentContainer(ThirdContainer&)
     : mFirstContainer(*this), mSecondContainer(*this) { };

     ~ParentContainer(); 

     void addMemberToThirdContainer() {
        mThirdContainer.addMember();
        notify();
     }; 

     void delMemberOfThirdContainer() {
        mThirdContainer.delMember();
        notify();
     };

 private:
     std::vec<int>& getMemberOfThirdContainer() {
        return mThirdContainer.getMember();
     };

     void notify() {
        auto vec = getMemberOfThirdContainer();
        mFirstContainer.update(vec);
        mSecondContainer.update(vec);
     };

     ThirdContainer& mThirdContainer;
     FirstContainer  mFirstContainer;
     SecondContainer mSecondContainer; 
 };
```

Then in FirstContainer and SecondContainer something like:

```
 class ParentContainer;

 class FirstContainer {
 public:
      FirstContainer(ParentContainer&);
      ~FirstContainer(); 

      void update(std::vector<int>& vec);

 private:
      ParentContainer& mParentContainer;
 };
```

In FirstContainer and SecondContainer I will have access to ThirdContainer by doing: 
 
mParentContainer.addMemberToThirdContainer and mParentContainer.DelMemberOfThirdContainer. 
 
And I will get notification. I mean I guess ....

Comment: Are the two object sharing *ownership* of the third object? Or do they need a non-owning pointer or reference to the third object?

Comment: First, a short language nitpick: A class describes how instances of this class look like. Instances of classes and other types (pointers, integers etc) are objects. That much just to get the meaning clear and because "sharing object between two class" is a bit unclear. Now, concerning your question, it's impossible to tell whether what you describe is smart, because there is way too little info. I'd suggest you start with what you want to achieve instead of starting with a possibly flawed approach to that.

Comment: FirstContainer and SecondContainer shouldn't have ownership over the ThirdContainer. The ThirdContainer is a sort of model, it should exist even without the two others (the opposite is false). Thanks for the help

Comment: Hey ulrich, What I want is to have two class communicating with the same instance of a third class. And that whenever a change is made in the shared instance, the class sharing it are notify. In the future the two class may shared more than one instance of a third class.

Answer (score 0):

If you like using libraries, you can use any library that provide Signal/Slot system, like Boost or Qt.

If you don't like libraries, you should try to

1. Create an interface (in C++, just an abstract class with pure virtual method, `onModified` for example:

   ```
   class ThirdContainerListener {
       public: virtual void onContainerModified() = 0;
       // Virtual: is to make it overridable
       //  = 0: is the C++ way to say "abstract", 
       //         which means this function MUST be overridden.
   };
   ```
2. Make a `vector` of pointers to listeners (to be safe, try to use smart-pointers, like `shared_ptr`) {This goes inside the ThirdContainer}

   ```
   vector<shared_ptr<ThirdContainerListener>> listeners;
   ```
3. Make (also inside the ThirdContainer), a function that adds listener, like that

   ```
   void addNewListener(shared_ptr<ThirdContainerListener> container) {
       listeners.push_back(container); // Adds the pointer to the listeners
   }
   ```
4. Hide your real container, like that

   ```
   private: vector<int> list;
   ```
5. Make a private function that calls all listeners, to be used LOCALLY

   ```
   private: void callAllListeners() {
       // Traverse through all the listeners
       for(shared_ptr<ThirdContainerListener> listener: listeners) {
           // Call each one's overridden function
           listener->onContainerModified();
       }
   }
   ```
6. Expose functions that modify your container, those call all listeners, like that

   ```
   public: void addData(int d) {
               list.push_back(d);
               callAllListeners();
           }

   // Also you could make "removeDataByIndex", "addManyData", etc...
   ```
7. Use `shared_ptr<ThirdContainer>` in both First and Second container, to ensure your classes wouldn't leak memory or point to nothing (dangling pointer)

Comment: Hey Thanks for the answer. This is how i'm doing this right now, is there a way to achieve the same thing without having broadcaster/listener pattern ?

Comment: If you JUST want your two other containers to be updated,    just use the last part, which is use a `shared_ptr<ThirdContainer>` in **both** containers. This makes any change happen in one, happens in the other, because `shared_ptr` is just a pointer, which means that the two point to the same object. But if you want others to listen to this change, I don't think there is other way than using broadcaster/listener

Comment: The thing is that I have a lot of instance of ThirdContainer and I only want one to be listen to (the selected one). I don't want all my ThirdContainer to hold a vector of pointers to listeners. Is there any way to manage that ?

Comment: If I understand you correctly,  you can make the `vector`,  in the form of `shared_ptr<vector<ThirdContainerListener>>`, so the listeners could be shared (but I don't think it is a good idea)

Comment: Yes, I have multiple instance of ThirdContainer living at the same time and only one of FirstContainer and SecondContainer. When a ThirdContainer instance is Selected I want the FirstContainer and the SecondContainer to listen to it. I would like to avoid having the vector of listener on all my ThirdContainer instance, only on the one selected.

Comment: What about making the `ThirdContainer` has a pair of pointers?  Like that `std::pair<shared_ptr<FirstContainer>, shared_ptr<SecondContainer>>` ?? Then you call them when changing something?  And use something like factory that selects a ThirdContainer: creates FirstContainer, and SecondContainer, these factories create, sets the singleton to the newly created object, and set the selected ThirdContainer 's FirstContainer and SecondContainer ???

Answer (score 0):

> When the `ThirdContainer` is modified, I want the two others to update using `getThirdContainerMembers()`.

Why? This does not really make much sense to me. Or at least - I don't understand your motivation. Why can't the two containers just get the members when they actually need them, rather than once on every update? Or better yet - why get a copy of the members at all, when you can possibly just keep the members in `ThirdContainer` and iterate them in there?

Now, you could say "Maybe the iterator gets invalidated during such access". But that's also an issue during the call to `getThirdContainerMembers()`.

> ThirdContainer has a list of listener and a method: addNewListener.

I don't like this approach, and would advise you to consider whether you really want to follow it.

I believe it is more fitting for interpreted languages, which have dynamically-typed objects, to which you can add or remove functionality on the fly, or at least they have interpreter/virtual-machine-provided mechanisms for observation and introspection. With such languages, your `ThirdContainer` doesn't have to be designed in advance to support listeners.

With C++, however, you will have to impose on the encapsulated design of ThirdContainer (or at least - inherit from an existing design), so that it supports listeners). But then, another time you would need to listen on some other event, and you'll again need to subclass or alter the interface of `ThirdContainer` - no, I'd rather not.

Instead, consider having whoever adds elements to the `ThirdContainer` be responsible for also updating the `FirstContainer` and `SecondContainer` instances which share it; or avoiding updates altogether.

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the Answer. The three container form a MVC pattern in an audio plugin. In the GUI there is two main part which are represent in my problem by the FirstContainer and the SecondContainer. This two class are embedding Controller and View capabilities. They hold a reference to the model(the ThirdContainer) for interaction. The user can click on both part to add member to the model. When a new member is added to the model, the FirstContainer and SecondContainer must add children(new part of the gui) to their vector and pass them a reference to the model new member for interaction.

Comment: "Instead, consider having whoever adds elements to the ThirdContainer be responsible for also updating the FirstContainer and SecondContainer instances which share it; or avoiding updates altogether" Is this something like the edited part of my answer ?